# Problemas en strings con las barras diagonales, Pyhton

Tags: python, str-replace

Les explico mi código y mi problema:
El código carga una imagen, a través de una ruta completa, o sea `C:\users\elias\pictures\etc`. Por lo que sé, Python no admite `\` en la imagen, sino que hay que cambiarlo por `/`.

```
direccion_imagen = input("Dirección imagén {}: ".format(i + 1))
direccion_imagen_l = direccion_imagen.replace("\", "/")
imagen = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), direccion_imagen_l)
```

Me da un error en el `replace`, desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías agregar el error así es más fácil ver el problema, pero supongo que es por la barra invertida que funciona como caracter de escape ([más info acá](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)). Deberías usar doble barra invertida `"\\"`, en el link de arriba te explica el  porqué de esto.

Answer (score 3):

### El problema

La barra `\` dentro de unas comillas tiene significado especial en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación. Dependiendo de qué carácter aparezca después de ella, significa una cosa u otra. Por ejemplo, casos famosos:

- `\n` --> Nueva línea (para hacer avanzar el cursor a la siguiente)
- `\"` --> Comillas. Es una forma de poder meter unas comillas dentro de las comillas, por ejemplo: `"Me dijo: \"No lo sé\""` Sin el `\` delante no habría forma pues se tomarían por el final de la cadena (en python se puede elegir poner la cadena entre comillas simples para evitar este problema, pero aún así lo anterior también es válido)

  Este por cierto es precisamente el caso que te causa problemas, ya que `"\"` se entiende como un `"` que inicia una cadena, un carácter "comillas" dentro de esa cadena y no se encuentra dónde estaría el `"` que terminaría la cadena.
- `\\` --> Carácter `\`. Ya que ese carácter es especial, meterlo "directamente" no es posible, pero metiéndolo de esta forma ya sería posible.

### Soluciones

Como se deduce de lo anterior, puedes meter la barra duplicada:

```
direccion_imagen_l = direccion_imagen.replace("\\", "/")
```

Pero python tiene otra solución, especialmente útil si el carácter `\` va a aparecer muchas veces dentro de tu cadena, para evitar tener que duplicarlo. Esto es bastante frecuente en expresiones regulares.

La solución es usar cadenas *raw* que se indican con una `r` delante de las comillas de apertura. En este tipo de cadenas el carácter `\` ya no tiene significado especial por lo que puedes meterlo libremente. A cambio, no podrás meter un "nueva línea" usando `\n` (porque lo que se guardará será literalmente un carácter `\` seguido de un carácter `n`).

Usando esta sintaxis:

```
direccion_imagen_l = direccion_imagen.replace(r"\", "/")
```

## Nota adicional

Dices al principio de tu pregunta (y yo lo había pasado por alto):

> El código carga una imagen, a través de una ruta completa, o sea `C:\users\elias\pictures\etc`. Por lo que sé, Python no admite `\` en la imagen, sino que hay que cambiarlo por `/`.

Esto **no es así**. En una ruta Windows perfectamente puede aparecer el carácter `\`.

El único problema que puedes tener es si en tu código asignas esa ruta a una variable, por ejemplo así:

```
ruta = "C:\users\elias\pictures\etc"
```

porque en este caso el carácter `\` es interpretado de forma especial, como se explicó más arriba (en particular se trata de `\u` que es el prefijo para insertar caracteres Unicode). Este problema se resolvería poniendo una `r` delante de la cadena, o duplicando cada `\` como ya hemos visto.

No obstante, en el código de ejemplo que proporcionas, la cadena no se inicializa desde el código, sino que se lee del usuario mediante un `input()`. En este caso no hay problema ninguno. Las cadenas leidas con `input()` (o desde un fichero) son siempre *raw*, es decir, si aparece un `\` en ellas no se interpreta como especial.

Por tanto **no necesitas convertir** la entrada del usuario para cambiar `\` por `/`.

Comment: Muchas, pero muchas gracias. Me has salvado jaja. Ya sabía que si le agregás la "r" podés utilizar esas barras, pero no sabía cómo aplicarla. Gracias <3

Comment: @EliasLengrube Releyendo tu pregunta me he dado cuenta de algo importante y he añadido una aclaración en mi respuesta.

Comment: @EliasLengrube [acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) si respondió a tu pregunta.